# Scala: Write a function to swap a number in place without using temporary variables

Tags: scala

Write a function to swap a number in place without using temporary variables in Scala. The function parameters are immutable, so how can we avoid using temporary variables to implement the function?

The solution in C/C++ is:

```
void swap(int a, int b) {
    a = a - b;
    b = b + a;
    a = b - a;
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}
```

What will be the equivalent solution in Scala since in `def swap(a: Int, b: Int): Unit` a and b both are immutable if I am not mistaken?

Comment: Why do you want to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: The question was asked in "Cracking the Coding Interview" book and I was trying to do that in Scala.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you mean. If you call `swap(1,2)` what do you expect back? `List(2,1)`?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: If the solution means that `a` receives `b`'s value, and `b` receives `a`'s value, then `a` and `b` are _not_ immutable. If the variables are mutable then look up [XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

Comment: If I am not wrong, a and b are immutable if we use them in Scala function like **def swap(a: Int, b: Int): Unit**.

Comment: So your question is _really_, "how to receive mutable parameters", and the answer is, "the JVM doesn't allow it".

Comment: That means, it is not possible without using temporary variables?

Comment: It's not possible _with_ temporary variables. It's not possible, period. If the values of `a` and `b` have to change then they are, by definition, mutable, and that means they cannot be received parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution for C++ is not the best one, because it might cause integer overflow if `a` or `b` is big enough.

The right solution would be using `xor`:

```
a = a ^ b;
b = b ^ a;
a = b ^ a;
```

But this kind of trick makes sense only if variables are mutable, so in your Scala version, you'd have to reassign function parameters to *vars*.

Another issue is, you should **never** do this in production code. 
This algorithm is called [xor swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) and was beneficial on some early processors, but it's not useful now. It gives you no benefit of better performance and is less readable that plainly using a temporary variable.

Comment: Your answer is based on C++ but I need that in Scala without using any temporary variables.

Comment: You can't do that unless variables are mutable. If they are mutable you can just do it as in C++.

Answer (score 2):

As has been established, it can't be done as a method or function. What you *can* do is create a `class` with constructor parameters, which *can* be mutable.

```
class Swap(var a:Int, var b:Int) {
  a ^= b
  b ^= a
  a ^= b
  println(s"a:$a, b:$b")
}
```

Now every time you create a new `Swap` instance, the values of the constructor parameters will be swapped.

```
val myswap = new Swap(4, 579)  //sends "a:579, b:4" to STDOUT
```

A rather pointless exercise.

Comment: I think the question is not applicable to Scala.